# WooCommerce Distance Rate Shipping causing tax rate to reset

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am on the verge of losing it with this problem. So what I am attempting is to apply *Zero rate* tax rate when a specific coupon ('*12345*') is applied to the order. This site also has the plugin **WooCommerce Distance Rate Shipping** installed which adds its own costs and tax to the order based on billing distance.

While the billing address fields are empty, the following code successfully detects the coupon in question and sets tax rate to 'Zero Rate':

```
function apply_matched_coupons() {

    $coupon_code = '12345'; 

    if ( !is_admin() && WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) {
        $tax_class = 'Zero rate';
    }
    return $tax_class;
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class','apply_matched_coupons' );
```

But when an address is typed in the billing fields, the Woocommerce order update AJAX works and the **WooCommerce Distance Rate Shipping** plugin reads the billing addresss, re-checks its rules, applies its costs and also adds its tax. Hence, overwriting my Zero Tax rate set earlier. Screenshot is attached. I believe a hook like `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` may work which fires each time the order is updated on checkout, but can't figure out exactly how to set it.

The plugin's page [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-distance-rate-shipping/) does show an example to set the `$rule_cost` to `0` with this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_distance_rate_shipping_rule_cost_distance_shipping', function( $rule_cost, $rule, $distance, $package ) {
    $order_total = $package['contents_cost'];
    if ( $order_total > 100 && $distance <= 5 ) {
        $rule_cost = 0;
    }

  return $rule_cost;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Could this help in any way?

[screenshot of extra tax added by the said plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bjpd.jpg)